# Error proyecto/solucion de Visual Studio "No se pueden cargar 2 o mas puntos de interrupción"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

En cualquier versión Visual Studio (tengo 17 y 19) cuando cierro y abro de nuevo se pierden los archivos "abiertos" que he estado trabajando (el contenido si lo guarda), los puntos de interrupción también se pierden y el proyecto que arranca de inicio vuelve hacer el default (el primer proyecto en la solución que cree), que aunque no es un problema grave es molesto y tardado cuando trabajo para realizar otras actividades, ¡ayuda!.

Answer (score 0):

revisa los siguiente en el menú (lo pongo en inglés ya que así tengo mi Visual studio) : `Tools/Options/Environment/Startup` en la parte `At Startup` verifica que no tengas establecido `Empty environment`

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta fue hace años, pero ojalá ayude a algunos. Hoy tuve el mismo problema, hasta que vi el sgte link: https://es.paperblog.com/error-visual-studio-2005-no-se-pueden-cargar-uno-o-mas-puntos-de-interrupcion-209508/
Literalmente la solución fue eliminar el archivo con la extensión *.suo que se coloca al lado del archivo *.sln, pero en mi caso ese archivo no estaba al lado, tuve que mostrar los elementos ocultos dentro de la carpeta y pude hallar ese archivo y lo eliminé, corrí nuevamente el programa y ya no salió ese apestoso error.

[image: captura]